# Change the following to take in account for the new year

Tags: sql-server

I'm very new to sql so im not sure how i would go about changing the line below to take in account for the new year. The sql server query i'm running will run on January 1st of 2014. Will this work in sql server 2008 or will it need to be changed for the new year to capture 2013?

```
DT.[DOS-DATE] between convert(date,GETDATE()-7) and convert(date,GETDATE())
```

Comment: There is no year-dependent processing in this code. You need to clarify what you mean by "take in account for the new year"

Comment: if it runs on the 1st of 2014 will it grab December 26th 2013 through 1st of January 2014? or would it need to be modified to do so?

Comment: Is `DOS-DATE` a date column or `DATETIME`? Do you want the query to run differently if you run it at midnight, versus noon, versus 8 PM, versus 11:59 PM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query takes records between the last 7 days and today. The year does not matter in that condition.

Comment: this is a scheduled query. so if it runs on the 1st of 2014 will it grab December 26th 2013 through the 1st of January 2014? or would it need to be modified to do so?

Comment: the condition substracts 7 days from the current date, no matter what date.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use explicit operators on date. Also, no reason to call `GETDATE()` twice. Try this instead:

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME = GETDATE()
...
DT.[DOS-DATE] between convert(date,DATEADD(day, -7, @Now)) and convert(date,@Now)
```

However, technically your existing code will work.

Also, you may want to take a look at this for potential issues with using `BETWEEN`:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: so on the 1st of January 2014 it will grab December 26th 2013 to the 1st of January 2014?

Comment: Yes, it just subtracts 7 days from the current date.